# Does anyone know how would I create bottom navigation tabs in react native? What would I need to download?

Tags: react-native

I tried following youtube tutorials on how to create bottom navigation tabs but they seem to have downloaded something already. What would I need to download for a bottom navigation tab?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is one option, you can follow the steps explained there:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/